# Sony Xperia Z3 (Compact) Battery life after update to Lollipop

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia-z3

If you already updated your **Sony Xperia Z3** (Compact) to **Lollipop**, what is your experience (and what we can expect) with the **battery life in Stamina** mode while the phone is idle?

Xperia can have **couple of days of light use** when on Stamina mode and Hangouts/LocationHistory off in KitKat.

Is it comparable, does it get noticeable better or worse after upgrade to Lollipop?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: That's quite impressive; I'm assuming you've got Ultra Stamina mode enabled to get that? (so, Wifi off when screen is off etc etc).

I've not seen any noticeable difference myself after the upgrade, but I only have Stamina mode enabled with 'Extended Usage' and 'Queue Background Data' turned on.

Comment: Yes, I ask about the Stamina mode, where is the biggest advantage of the Xperia prolonging the battery life when you don't use the phone often. If you have an experience with Stamina Lollipop, feel free to answer below. I would also appreciate to see a screenshot of your battery stats, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to Stamina mode since I don't use it often, but I had great battery life in regular mode on KitKat. With light talking, texting, and browser/FB use, I could easily go more than 24 hours without recharging my phone. Since upgrading to Lollipop (4-5 days ago), my phone goes from 100% charged at 7am to 7% charged at 5pm -- with *very* little use -- terrible!  I hope there's a patch for this, b/c I am so disappointed. No real visible upgrade to Lollipop, so frankly, I'd rather go back to KitKat.

Comment: I would like to downgrade to kitkat as well. The question is how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

My battery life started to deplete very quickly after upgrading to Lollipop. I experimented with Stamina mode to try to get back to the battery life I used to have on my Z3C, but it actually made it worse! Google play services was keeping my mobile radio active almost 100% of the time. I moved back to regular mode and I'm getting about 15-20 hours of battery with normal use.

Google play services still consumes the most battery on my phone, but it seems to be at least reasonable now. Definitely looking for a patch or some sort of fix - very disappointed.

Comment: I have the same problem for xperia z1 compact

Answer (score 0):

My friend saw a huge decrease in battery duration after making the Lollipop switch. The battery would not last a whole day with light usage. 
Her workaround is to disable location services when not using them. This prevents Google Services from activating, which apparently is a currently a huge power drain in this build. Now she is back to at least a couple days between having to recharge.